# WOOF Products Filter plugin and out of stock variations issue in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On woocommerce I am using the [WOOF Products Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/) plugin. When using size attribute filter, sometimes products appear even when the variation is **out of stock**.

I've asked woof support team and they said that it's not related to the plugin.

I figure that then I delete the attribute the filter is working fine, I want to ask if it right solution? why woocommerce searching by attribute when the variation is outofstock? (I heard it can be related to flatsome theme, is it true?)

I wondering how to implement the code to remove all the outofstock attribute and how to add attribute when the variation will be instock again.

using woocoomerce, theme is flatsome and filter plugin is woof filer product ajax

Comment: It's not possible by default in woocommerce to handle variable products stock visibility (stock status) based on it's variations visibility.

Comment: So I need to remove the outofstock attributes? do you know any option to set outofstock attributes as invisable?

Comment: You can't as it's something really necessary and needed by Woocommerce…